# Knockout : using useOnlyNativeEvents along with Jquery event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

As per the [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)

> Knockout will use jQuery, if it is present, for handling UI events. To disable this behavior and instruct Knockout to always use native event handling, you can set the following option in your code before calling `ko.applyBindings`
>
> `ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;`

But setting the above property doesn't block the event attached using jquery.

**HTML**

```
<input id="test" type="text" data-bind="value:defaultVm.Temp,event:{change:defaultVm.ChangeEvt}"/>
<label data-bind="text:defaultVm.Temp" style="color:#ffff"/>
```

**JS**

```
  defaultVm = function() {

    var temp = ko.observable("tests");
    
    var changeEvt = function(){
        alert("I was called");
    }

    return {
      Temp: temp,
      ChangeEvt : changeEvt
    }
  }();
  
  ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true; // Doesnt change any behaviour
  ko.applyBindings(defaultVm);
     
     
$('#test').on('change',function()
{
    alert("I was called");
});
```

Whats wrong with my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxuwxa1x/), Why setting the property `ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;` doesn't change the default behaviour?

Comment: If `useOnlyNativeEvents = false`, knockout internally uses jquery for event handling. If you set it to true it will probably go the pure javascript route. It won't stop you from attaching events outside of your `viewModel`. You can go through this [github issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useOnlyNativeEvents` option does *not* prevent you from attaching any event handlers. Knockout can't block the DOM api from being used by other pieces of code... You'll have to enforce that in your own code.

What it *does* do:

The event binding (and bindings that extend it, like `click`) passes two arguments to its listener method: `$data` and `event`. When not using jQuery, the type of `event` is [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

With jQuery, the type becomes a [`jQuery.Event` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```js
const logType = (d, e) => {
  console.log("Regular event:", e instanceof Event);
  console.log("jQuery event:", e instanceof jQuery.Event);
}

ko.applyBindings(
  { onClick: logType },
  document.querySelector("#btn1")
)

ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;
ko.applyBindings(
  { onClick: logType },
  document.querySelector("#btn2")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1" data-bind="click: onClick">is jQuery event</button>
<button id="btn2" data-bind="click: onClick">is regular event</button>
```